# running Js test getting error window is undefined

Tags: javascript, karma-jasmine, jshint

running JS tests using karma + jasmine

I get an error 'window' is not defined, I've added defensive code to detect browser like so

```
if ((typeof window !== 'undefined') && window['test']) {
       ...
}
```

but still get an error , how can type of window be defined and the window be  undefined at the same time ?

**Edit** :

The exact error is : *'window' is not defined*

Comment: I think your title is wrong the error is window is UNdefined, right ? can you copy and paste the exact error

Comment: sounds very peculiar indeed. Perhaps if we can see more of your code? or more of the error, like a stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was missing was this

```
/*jshint browser: true*/
```